# Is anyone combining Google Search Autocompletion with Emacs/Helm?

Tags: helm

When you go to Google or to the address bar, and type your search query, you see various completion candidates for your query as suggested ed by google.

I thought it would be great if you could fire Helm with a shortcut key, and then type your query. The candidates are delivered by the autocompletion suggestions from Google.

I planned to develop a Helm source, in order to get this working. To find a way to connect Emacs/Helm with Google API for their search autocompletion, I found this: https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/07/update-on-autocomplete-api.html

Since the CSE is a paid service, I wonder if there are any Emacs packages that succesfully connects with Google's API/CSE? Then I could figure out how they did it.

Comment: I think you're looking for Google's autocompletion without its search engine, so I don't think this is what you're looking for, but it might still be helpful to look at the command `helm-google-suggest`, which is built into `helm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Since I don't have enough reputation here so far, I'd like to leave my message here.*

As Aaron has suggested, I'd like you to give it a try. `helm-google-suggest` worth trying, and I'm using it either.